# Convert hex values to characters

Tags: perl, unicode

I have strings like: "Film-DVD \x{bb}Once / The Swell Season (Collector's Edition\x{ab} John Carney" which are the result of Data::Dumper.

Now I want the hex-values \x{bb}, \x{ab} to be replaced with corresponding characters » and «.

I already tried:

```
$a =~ s/\\x\{(.{2})\}/chr(hex($1))/eg;
```

But this returns me "Film-DVD �Once / The Swell Season (Collector's Edition� John Carney"

Do you have any ideas what i could do?

Comment: Have you set your output encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted is correct.

The problem appears to be that you forgot to tell Perl to encode your output. This is normally done using

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```